# cannot associate program with context menu action

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I installed a program called [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) and it's pretty nice; But one thing it does during installation is to forcefully add a context menu item to open the current folder in it.

Unfortunately, since day 1, this has been broken. I've tried setting the association manually and it doesn't work. Setting an association with the program doesn't yield any different results. Is there anything else that can be done? I've even tried removing it from the registry.

This is all happening on Windows 10 x64.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Run regedit.exe
- Go to

  > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Directory/Background/shell/GitKraken/command
- Change

  > "%somedir%\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe
  >   --process-start-args="-p **%L**"

  to

  > "%somedir%\gitkraken\update.exe" --processStart=gitkraken.exe
  >   --process-start-args="-p **%V**"

Comment: @Ciel, this is the answer, please mark it as so. Thanks for the tip @Veress!

Comment: The problem is that it does not open the current repository on the program

Comment: @jordanbtucker I am so sorry. I thought I marked this months ago. I'm really, really sorry. Thank you again so much.

Comment: I can confirm that this fixes the problem and does indeed open the selected folder as a repo.

Comment: If it doesn't open the right repository, try changing `%V` to `\"%V\"`. I had the same issue since the repo path had spaces in it.

Answer (score 1):

This context menu item will work as you would expect if you right click the `.git` folder itself.

Apologies for answering on a very old thread but I was having this problem myself recently so maybe it will help someone in the future.

Comment: So you're saying that you have to find the .git folder inside a folder, and the right-click function of GitKraken will correctly handle that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to open GitKraken and try to find a setting where you can disable shell integration. This should get rid of the option in the explorer right-click menu. If you find such a setting you can always try re-enabling it and see if it works after that. You indicated you already attempted doing a registry edit, but just to make sure you're doing it correctly, here's a link to a how-to on the topic:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/
GitKraken apparently installs this in an usual way, so it might be under background/shell or background/shellex instead of shell and shellex. Source:
https://codinglifeofasoftwaredeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/gitkraken-woes/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any such option to disable shell integration. I've followed the instructions at that link, and the menu item still persists.

Comment: I will investigate the second link now, thank you

Comment: Did that resolve the issue or is the problem still occurring?

Comment: Unfortunately, something came up and I was not yet able to try again. I'll try as soon as I can.

Comment: Can you post the registry changes you made?

Comment: @BlackEyedGhost, the way GitKraken installs the shell commands is not unusual. It installs a command for right clicking on a folder and one for right-clicking on the *background* of a folder. Visual Studio Code does the same thing.